# Flash stage/root width & height always 100?

Tags: flash

```
trace(root.width);
trace(stage.width);
```

Both these return 100. Same for height. The stage has been set to 1024x620 in the editor.

I'm using CS5, Flash version 10, windows7 64-bit.

I don't get what's going wrong here. I'm trying to center something and it keeps coming out like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `stage.stageWidth` to get the actual width of the stage.  `stage.width` is returning the width of the bounding box of stage, which will only be as large as the content you attach to it.

Note: if you don't set the scaleMode of stage to 'noScale', `stage.stageWidth` will always return the initial stage size, regardless of any resizing.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#stageWidth

Comment: 'which will only be as large as the content you attach to it'. Gotta remember that one.